# Docker with Laravel 4.2, connecting to DB throws error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-4

I need to get an old version of a Laravel app working.
It is using Laravel version 4.2.2.

I have a docker setup:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  laravel:
    depends_on:
      - database
    ...

  database:
    image: mysql:5
    hostname: database
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: myuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass
```

I added database data to config (Laravel 4.2)

```
 'connections' => array (

            'mysql'  => array (
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => 'database', // as name of db container
                'database'  => 'mydb',  // this database exists, I can see in PhpMyAdmin
                'port'      => '3306',
                'username'  => 'root',  // I can login with these credentials in PhpMyAdmin and CLI
                'password'  => 'mypass',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
            ),
...
```

I can login to a phpmyadmin container with these credentials, and I also can login from the CLI of laravel container with `mysql -h database -u root -p`.

If I dump the connection in Laravel `Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php` class, I see that the correct config is being used.

```
public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
    {
        $username = array_get($config, 'username');

        $password = array_get($config, 'password');

        // dd($dsn);
        // dd($config);
        // dd($username); dd($password);


        return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }
```

Gives:

- `string(59) "mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;dbname=mydb"`
- `array(11) { ["driver"]=> string(5) "mysql" ["host"]=> string(8) "database" ["port"]=> string(4) "3306" ["database"]=> string(6) "mydb" ["username"]=> string(4) "root" ["password"]=> string(21) "mypass" ["charset"]=> string(4) "utf8" ["collation"]=> string(15) "utf8_unicode_ci" ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["unix_socket"]=> string(27) "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" ["name"]=> string(5) "mysql" }`
- root` (username)
- `mypass` (password)

Why do I still get the error?

Comment: One way to test this, get the IP for the database container and use that as host.

Comment: @abestrad I already tried that, same error, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Your `username` in the dockerconfig and Laravel config is different

Comment: @samuelj90 Yes, but I try to login with `root` right now.

Comment: @samuelj90 for the sake of experiment I tried logging in with the other user and I get the same error

Comment: Through which way you tried to connect with mysql using the other user

Comment: @samuelj90 I simply replaced the username in Laravel config with "myuser" (password remains the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
If you look at the `$dsn`-value in `Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php` `createConnection`:

```
string(59) "mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;dbname=mydb"
```

You see that `host=database` is simply missing, even though I added it in laravel config.

Adding it manually solves this problem:

```
$dsn= "mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;host=database;dbname=mydb";
```

Even though I added the host in the config, I found out that in another `database`-config there was a `unix_socket`-value added to `mysql` configuration. Laravel takes either the socket or the host information. My `host`-value has not been overriden, but the presence of `unix_socket`-value in the other configuration prevented connection via `host`.

So I simply removed the `unix_socket` in another config.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reasons for `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]` is as follows

1. MYSQL is not running
2. Incorrect database settings
3. Insufficient server resources

Based on the analysis of your scenario, the possible reasons is the incorrect database settings

Possible recommendation from my side is to find the right database settings in Laravel.

- Make sure the host is correct
- Make sure the username is correct
- Make sure the password is correct

In most of the cases the problem lies on the host resolution in docker for that I recommend you to find the right hostname and port that the laravel container can able to connect with the mysql container

Following the steps described in this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose) or verifying the steps with your existing system may solve your problem.